# Loop Echoing Database Entries

Tags: php, mysql

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `databse` WHERE `user`='$username'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows != 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $id = $row ['id'];
    $dbinfo1 = $row ['dbinfo1'];
    $dbinfo2 = $row ['dbinfo2'];
    $dbinfo3 = $row ['dbinfo3'];
    $dbinfo4 = $row ['dbinfo4'];
    $numberofenteries = 0;

        if ($dbinfo1 && $dbinfo2 && $dbinfo3)
        {
            $numberofenteries++;

        }
        echo "<div>$dbinfo1</div><div>$dbinfo2 $dbinfo3 $numberofenteries</div>";

    }
} 
else
{
    echo "<div>There are no database enteries.</div>";
}
```

I have been work on this code to tell me database entries in a loop so it creates a list of all the entries for me. The problem I am having is that I want the code to not make another entry if it already exists, but instead add 1 to the `numberofenteries` variable.

Example:

Instead of

Apples Oranges Bananas 1
Apples Oranges Bananas 1
Apples Oranges Peaches 1
Apples Oranges Pineapples 1
Apples Oranges Pineapples 1
Apples Oranges Pineapples 1

I need

Apples Oranges Bananas 2
Apples Oranges Peaches 1
Apples Oranges Pineapples 3

Any help whatsoever is greatly appreciated.

So after taking a look at some feedback. I added the `count` and `group by` and it displays the database entries but still shows double entries and now it's not displaying a number.

Here is the current code.

```
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE `user`='$username'");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $reasult = mysql_query("
    SELECT *, count(1) as numberofenteries FROM `database` WHERE `user`='$username'    Group By        branch,firstname,lastname
    ");

$numberofenteries = $reasult ['numberofenteries'];

if ($rows != 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $branch = $row['branch'];
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
        $lastname = $row ['lastname'];

        echo "<div>$branch $firstname $lastname $numberofenteries </div>";
    }
} 
else
{
    echo "<div>There is no entries in the database.</div>";
}
```

Another Update
I got it to stop displaying duplicates of the same information in the database, but it still isn't counting them and displaying the number.

Comment: your history shows you have habit of not following up and accepting answers....caution : this is bad habit on community! :)

Comment: I had just got off work when I posted this and went to bed. Now that I am up, I will try out the information I was provided and see if it works, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

count the rows as follows :

```
"SELECT *, count(1) as numberofenteries 
 FROM `databse` 
 WHERE `user`='$username'
 Group By dbinfo1,dbinfo2,dbinfo3,dbinfo4" /* to club the result*/
```

here `count(1)` will go on incrementing when a row is found

then, to retrieve this value, simply do :

```
$numberofenteries = $row ['numberofenteries'];
```

Comment: Surely this should be done at the database level with group by, rather than looping in PHP?

Comment: @JohnBarça : surely mate, amend needs to be done at query level! :)